# SAS proc stream : weird linebreaks

Tags: stream, sas, proc

Server: Unix, Client: IE Edge 
Part of my code:

```
%let P_debug_log = %str(<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='_DEBUG' VALUE='LOG'>);
proc stream outfile=_webout quoting=both resetdelim='_do' ASIS;
BEGIN
  %if "&_whattodo" ne "print" %then %do;
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>                                       
        function subForm(f,v) {
            if (v !== '') {
              $('#'+ f).append('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="'+ v +'" VALUE="1">');
            }
            $('#'+f).submit();       
          } 
      $(document).ready(function() {                                                            
        $('#footButtons').append($('.footButton'));   /* move all elements with class=footButton to pageFooter */
        $('#footMessage').append($('.footMsg'));   
        $('form.log').append("&P_debug_log.");
      });                                                                               
    </script>
  %end;
;;;;
```

Output: 
The Problem is, that generated stream Output has linebreaks "somewhere" but not where expected (with Option ASIS it should be formatted like in my code).
This leads to unpredictable JavaScript Errors, e.g. when a linebreak is within a JavaScript string. 
It seems as if there is an implicit LRECL 1024. This would be OK if linebreaks would be set as expected.
Any hints?

This is the originally formatted Output (Page Source):

```
     <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>                  function subForm(f,v) {         if (v !== '') {           $('#'+ f).append('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="'+ v +'" VALUE="1">');         }          $('#'+f).submit();             }
        $(document).ready(function() {                        $('#footButtons').append($('.footButton'));            $('#footMessage').append($('.footMsg'));            $('form.log').append("
<INPUT TYPE=
'hidden
' NAME=
'_DEBUG
' VALUE=
'LOG
'
>");       });                         </script>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ASIS/PRESCOL option. You might want to raise it with SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `ASIS` option you have added to `proc stream`.

I'm not sure if this is an undocumented feature but it doesn't appear in the documentation so I'm assuming so.

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n12zrkr08eiacmn17lcv4fmt79tb.htm&locale=en

Once you remove that the weird line breaks disappear.

Searching around, it appears the ASIS option is something to do with attempting to preserve column alignment.

Comment: thank you. I found
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/1738-2014.pdf
but I guess you are right.
Removing the ASIS Option results in a stream with linebreaks ever 1024 Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have an answer, but it looks like the macro quoting is what is causing PROC STREAM to separate out the macro variable into multiple lines.
So if I run this simplified example:

```
%let P_debug_log = %str(<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='_DEBUG' VALUE='LOG'>);
filename tst temp;
proc stream outfile=tst quoting=both resetdelim='_do' ASIS;
BEGIN
$('form.log').append("&P_debug_log.");
;;;;
```

Then it generates this file:

```
$('form.log').append("
<INPUT TYPE='hidden
' NAME='_DEBUG
' VALUE='LOG
'>");
```

If you remove the `%STR()` from around the value of the macro variable then it only inserts line breaks before and after the full macro variable reference and not also around the quotes in the macro variable.

```
$('form.log').append("
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='_DEBUG' VALUE='LOG'>
");
```

If you remove the `quoting=both` option then the line breaks will be outside the quotes, whether or not you use macro quoting.

```
$('form.log').append(
"<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='_DEBUG' VALUE='LOG'>"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you all for your answers.
Robert Penridge was right.
Solution:
If you use PROC STREAM and want to include static code (as in my case: Javascript), then use &STREAMDELIM READFILE  instead of %include.
Reason: if there are (valid!) inline comments "//" (comment until next linebreak,) in the included code, it will lead to unpredictable results....
thanks a lot,
dbdb